# Muliple table joining with conditional statements

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to run a query in CodeIgniter:

The query is

```
"SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image
     WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id
          AND td_album.album_id='$id'
          AND (td_image.image_name='$name' OR td_image.image_id='$image_id');"
```

I wrote this query in CI using active record:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
                        ->from('td_image')
                        ->join('td_album', 'td_album.album_id = td_image.album_id')
                        ->like('td_image.image_id', $descp)
                        ->or_like('td_image.image_name', $descp)
                        ->like('td_album.album_id',$a_id)
                        ->get('', $this->limit, $this->offset);
```

But I face a problem. Suppose I have two albums with id `1` and `2`. I want to show images of album `1` only. The above CI AR query is returning results of all the images, i.e. displaying images of both  the albums, which should not happen.

Actually it should display images from album whose album_id is 1.

Now I realize the above CI AR query stands for:

```
"SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image
         WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id
              AND td_album.album_id LIKE'$id'
              OR td_image.image_name LIKE'$name' AND td_image.image_id LIKE'$image_id';"
```

and so it displays all the images. My requirement is to display images of only one album.

So, I need CI AR query to be equivalent to this MYSQL query

```
"SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image
             WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id
                  AND td_album.album_id LIKE'$id'
                  AND (td_image.image_name LIKE'$name' OR td_image.image_id LIKE'$image_id');"
```

How can I convert the last query to CI AR? I want a query having `like() or_like()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could just use the $this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE'); for a complex query.

i.e.

```
$My_SQL_Query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM td_album,td_image WHERE td_album.album_id=td_image.album_id AND td_album.album_id LIKE'$id' AND (td_image.image_name LIKE'$name' OR td_image.image_id LIKE'$image_id')");

 foreach($My_SQL_Query->result() as $Row){
    echo "-------<br />".print_r($Row)."<br />-------<br /><br />";
 }
```

Hope this is helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this problem a few days ago. Active Records does not support grouping a where clause in () so you need to put that part of the where clause in a variable.

```
$where = "(td_image.image_name LIKE'$name' OR td_image.image_id LIKE'$image_id')";
$this->db->where($where);
```